# Convert command output table to dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, subprocess

I am running the `'arp-scan -l'` command in a script. Currently my code returns this string variable result:

```
192.168.200.1   90:ef:68:f8:8b:c2       ZyXEL Communications Corporation
192.168.200.81  60:45:cb:6c:5e:3e       (Unknown)
192.168.200.83  0c:fe:45:4b:b8:98       Sony Interactive Entertainment Inc.
192.168.200.106 ac:84:c6:57:f7:19       TP LINK
192.168.200.72  50:dc:e7:67:bd:e0       (Unknown)
192.168.200.157 5c:52:1e:59:2c:d1       TP LINK
192.168.200.229 f8:62:14:5a:9e:c7       (Unknown)
```

If I just split this output it creates a list like so: `('ip\mac\sony interactive entertainment')`

I would like the output to be: `('ip','mac','sony interactive entertainment')`

My code so far:

```
arp_cmd = ['arp-scan', '-l']

run_command = subprocess.Popen(arp_cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output_bytes = run_command.communicate()[0]
output_str = output_bytes.decode("utf-8")
print(output_str.split('/n'))
```

OUTPUT:

`['192.168.200.1\t90:ef:68:f8:8b:c2\tZyXEL Communications Corporation\n192.168.200.81\t60:45:cb:6c:5e:3e\t(Unknown)\n192.168.200.81\t60:45:cb:6c:5e:3e\t(Unknown) (DUP: 2)\n192.168.200.83\t0c:fe:45:4b:b8:98\tSony Interactive Entertainment Inc.\n192.168.200.83\t0c:fe:45:4b:b8:98\tSony Interactive Entertainment Inc. (DUP: 2)\n192.168.200.106\tac:84:c6:57:f7:19\t(Unknown)\n192.168.200.72\t50:dc:e7:67:bd:e0\t(Unknown)\n192.168.200.150\t5c:f9:38:d1:25:b5\tApple, Inc.\n192.168.200.150\t5c:f9:38:d1:25:b5\tApple, Inc. (DUP: 2)\n192.168.200.157\t5c:52:1e:59:2c:d1\t(Unknown)\n192.168.200.229\tf8:62:14:5a:9e:c7\t(Unknown)']`

Comment: Maybe there are two tabs between the mac and name you can utilize?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### General Case

In general, `split` has a keyword `maxsplit` where you can specify the maximum number of splits to make. E.g.

```
>>> s = 'IP MAC Sony Interactive Entertainment'
>>> s.split(' ', maxsplit=2)
['IP', 'MAC', 'Sony Interactive Entertainment']
```

It will split the string by the number of times you specify in `maxsplit`, and the remainder will be cast to a single string.

---

### From Comment

Output is a list containing one string; where each line from the `arp` command is newline separated.

```
output = ['192.168.200.1\t90:ef:68:f8:8b:c2\tZyXEL Communications Corporation\n192.168.200.81\t60:45:cb:6c:5e:3e\t(Unknown)\n192.168.200.83\t0c:fe:45:4b:b8:98\tSony Interactive Entertainment Inc.\n192.168.200.83\t0c:fe:45:4b:b8:98\tSony Interactive Entertainment Inc. (DUP: 2)\n192.168.200.106\tac:84:c6:57:f7:19\t(Unknown)\n192.168.200.72\t50:dc:e7:67:bd:e0\t(Unknown)\n192.168.200.150\t5c:f9:38:d1:25:b5\tApple, Inc.\n192.168.200.150\t5c:f9:38:d1:25:b5\tApple, Inc. (DUP: 2)\n192.168.200.157\t5c:52:1e:59:2c:d1\t(Unknown)\n192.168.200.229\tf8:62:14:5a:9e:c7\t(Unknown)']
```

Split the single string in to a `list` containing each line from the `arp` command as a separate string.

```
>>> item_list = output[0].split('\n')
>>> item_list
['192.168.200.1\t90:ef:68:f8:8b:c2\tZyXEL Communications Corporation',
 '192.168.200.81\t60:45:cb:6c:5e:3e\t(Unknown)',
 ....]
```

Now, each line is simply `\t` separated - so no requirement for `maxsplit`. Take the first item, for example:

```
>>> item_one = item_list[0]
>>> item_one.split('\t')
['192.168.200.1', '90:ef:68:f8:8b:c2', 'ZyXEL Communications Corporation']
```

With that in mind, you could iterate over the full `item_list` to produce a list of lists:

```
>>> output_list = list()
>>> for item in item_list:
...     output.append(item.split('\t'))
...
>>> output_list
[['192.168.200.1', '90:ef:68:f8:8b:c2', 'ZyXEL Communications Corporation'],
 ['192.168.200.81', '60:45:cb:6c:5e:3e', '(Unknown)'],
....]]
```

---

### Crammed to one line

```
>>> [item.split('\t') for item in output[0].split('\n')]
```

Comment: I was just running `s.split('/n')`. Would maxsplit work if I have about 10 items in the list? It looks like it works for the first line and makes the rest of the table into a value.

Comment: Would you be able to provide the whole "output_str" value, what each line from the `arp` command is delimited by, and the entire output you're looking for as opposed to just one line? I should then be able to provide you with a full solution.

Comment: Right now I have it running as a subprocess command so it's scanning my home networking. I edit the post above with what it's currently outputting in terminal when I run it. It pretty much shows a table with IP, MAC, then the name tabbed over. The repeats on a new line for each device it finds. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for that - would you be able to provide your full output from your own split command?

Comment: It just kind of mashes things together

['192.168.200.1\t90:ef:68:f8:8b:c2\tZyXEL Communications Corporation\n192.168.200.81\t60:45:cb:6c:5e:3e\t(Unknown)\n192.168.200.83\t0c:fe:45:4b:b8:98\tSony Interactive Entertainment Inc.\n192.168.200.83\t0c:fe:45:4b:b8:98\tSony Interactive Entertainment Inc. (DUP: 2)\n192.168.200.106\tac:84:c6:57:f7:19\t(Unknown)\n192.168.200.72\t50:dc:e7:67:bd:e0\t(Unknown)\n192.168.200.150\t5c:f9:38:d1:25:b5\tApple, Inc.\n192.168.200.157\t5c:52:1e:59:2c:d1\t(Unknown)\n192.168.200.229\tf8:62:14:5a:9e:c7\t(Unknown)']

Comment: Let me know if you're still requiring different output.

Comment: No worries!! :)

Answer (score 1):

### Solution

Another way I was able to do it:

```py
import re

s = """
192.168.200.1   90:ef:68:f8:8b:c2       ZyXEL Communications Corporation
192.168.200.81  60:45:cb:6c:5e:3e       (Unknown)
192.168.200.83  0c:fe:45:4b:b8:98       Sony Interactive Entertainment Inc.
192.168.200.106 ac:84:c6:57:f7:19       TP LINK
192.168.200.72  50:dc:e7:67:bd:e0       (Unknown)
192.168.200.157 5c:52:1e:59:2c:d1       TP LINK
192.168.200.229 f8:62:14:5a:9e:c7       (Unknown)
"""

found = re.findall(r"(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(.*)\n?", s)

print(found)
## prints:
## [('192.168.200.1', '90:ef:68:f8:8b:c2', 'ZyXEL Communications Corporation'), ('192.168.200.81', '60:45:cb:6c:5e:3e', '(Unknown)'), ('192.168.200.83', '0c:fe:45:4b:b8:98', 'Sony Interactive Entertainment Inc.'), ('192.168.200.106', 'ac:84:c6:57:f7:19', 'TP LINK'), ('192.168.200.72', '50:dc:e7:67:bd:e0', '(Unknown)'), ('192.168.200.157', '5c:52:1e:59:2c:d1', 'TP LINK'), ('192.168.200.229', 'f8:62:14:5a:9e:c7', '(Unknown)')]
```

### Explanation

pattern = `(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(.*)\n?`

This solution uses regex to find the right strings. In this case: non-whitespace characters seperated by whitespace characters, and optionally finish with a newline.

Findall returns the result as a list of tuples (since we specified multiple groups)